# how to open the developer tools for a webview in chrome packaged apps?

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app, developer-tools

In chrome packged apps, i was able to to open the Developer Tools for a webview by right-clicking until a few weeks ago . However, after the chrome has been updated , it is impossible. (Chrome version is 29.0.1547.66)

Is it possible to enable the right click of webview as before ?  Or is there any api to open the developer tools for a webview?

Comment: Did you happen to change the frame to 'none'?  I noticed when I did that the right-click "Inspect Element" option is only available in non-draggable regions. Also, @user2296820 is correct.

Comment: What is 'non-draggable regions' mean?

Comment: There are two frame styles supported by packaged apps.  The default is 'chrome' which means the app will have the normal 'windows-style' border with the minimize/maximize/close buttons.  The second option is 'none'.  If your app has a style of 'none' you can still move the app window around by clicking in 'draggable' regions (usually the background).  In my simple test app only the input fields are non-draggable.  So if I right-click on an input field I have the "Inspect Element" option, but if I right-click in the background I don't.  HTH.

Comment: I understood the meaning of what you said. Perhaps, this problem is not in frame styles. i can see the border with the minimize/maximize/close buttons in my app. and i can open inspect element by right-clicking the most element, but only in webview element, it is impossible. i want to open the developer tools for a webview.  thanks for your comment. (Please understand that I can not be English well.)

Answer (score 6):

In M29, you can find webviews in the Other page in chrome://inspect. The interface for debugging webviews in chrome://inspect has improved significantly in Chrome canary recently. It'll now display webviews within an app underneath the app.

Comment: thanks for your answer. So, is there a way to be called direct development tools for a webview? Is it must go through chrome://inspect?